# shopware 6 twig add block inside of another block child div

Tags: twig, shopware, shopware6

i wanted to know if there is any solution to this problem in shopware 6. Many blocks have some child elements. E.g. if i want to add an checkbox to the checkout i need to replace the entire block. This causes complications to other plugins, which are using the same block too.

Shopware 6 twig:

```html
{% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control %}
                            <div class="form-check"> <!-- <-- child div -->
                                {% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control_checkbox %}
                                    <input type="checkbox"
                                           class="checkout-confirm-tos-checkbox form-check-input{% if formViolations.getViolations('/tos') is not empty %} is-invalid{% endif %}"
                                           required="required"
                                           id="tos"
                                           form="confirmOrderForm"
                                           name="tos"/>
                                {% endblock %}

                                {% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control_label %}
                                    <label for="tos"
                                           class="checkout-confirm-tos-label custom-control-label">
                                        {{ "checkout.confirmTermsText"|trans({
                                            '%url%': path('frontend.cms.page',{ id: config('core.basicInformation.tosPage') })
                                        })|raw }}
                                    </label>
                                {% endblock %}
                                <!-- add content/other block here -->
                            </div>
                        {% endblock %}
```

My twig:

```html
{% extends '@Storefront/storefront/page/checkout/confirm/index.html.twig' %}

{% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <!-- ! This isn't inside the child div of the block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control -->
    {% block page_checkout_confirm_shippingdata_control_checkbox %}
        <input type="checkbox"
               class="checkout-confirm-shippingdata-checkbox form-check-input{% if formViolations.getViolations('/shippingdata') is not empty %} is-invalid{% endif %}"
               required="required"
               id="shippingdata"
               form="confirmOrderForm"
               name="shippingdata"/>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block page_checkout_confirm_shippingdata_control_label %}
        <label for="shippingdata"
               class="checkout-confirm-shippingdata-label custom-control-label">
            {{ "checkout.confirmShippingdataText"|trans({
                '%url%': path('frontend.cms.page',{ id: config('core.basicInformation.tosPage') })
            })|raw }}
        </label>
    {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

Is there any solution to do that without js?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following but, if your 2nd templates extends from the 1st you've posted then neither the block `page_checkout_confirm_shippingdata_control_checkbox` nor `page_checkout_confirm_shippingdata_control_label` actually exists in the 1st template. So I don't know what you expect to happen?

Comment: The 1st template has the child div `<div class="form-check"`. I want to insert my own created blocks `page_checkout_confirm_shippingdata_control_checkbox` and `page_checkout_confirm_shippingdata_control_label` inside the child div. I can't just overwrite the `page_checkout_confirm_tos_control` cause other plugins may change this too. So in the 1st template i can't make any changes.

Comment: You can't append anything to a non-existing block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that specific case, why not just append the last block inside `.form-check`?

```
{% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control_label %}
    {{ parent() }}

    {% block page_checkout_confirm_shippingdata_control_checkbox %}
        ...
    {% endblock %}

    {% block page_checkout_confirm_shippingdata_control_label %}
        ...
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

In my opinion that's a valid approach to get inside `.form-check`. On the other hand I could see why it might not feel "clean" to append to the specific block for a label of another element. If you feel that way and there is no hurry, you could open a [pull request](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/guidelines/code/contribution) that adds a block that covers the inside of `.form-check`.

```
{% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control %}
    <div class="form-check">
        {% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control_form_check %}
            ...
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Once this is merged and released the forthcoming updates of your plugin may use that new block instead then.

Comment: Instead of overwriting the "original" theme files, OP could just create a "custom" base, define blocks inside the new base, without altering the original files and extend from the custom base - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/4fthx2)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So i'll do a pull request to github. Thanks again :)